# Merging Columns Inside Multi-Index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe which looks like this (sorry for the picture but I can't replicate the dataframe via code):

[example dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTJ6o.png)

Products are the same, but in different orders. Prices need to be separated.

I would like to have one single column for product and the others columns to be the prices, as follows:

[example desired dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNwgW.png)

Comment: "sorry for the picture but I can't replicate the dataframe via code" why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to create a multiIndex dataframe.

```
tuples = list(zip(*[
    ["a","a","b","b","c","c"],
    ["product","price","product","price","product","price"],
]))
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['apple', 1, 'oranges', 2, 'bananas', 1],
    ['oranges', 4, 'bananas', 3, 'oranges', 2],
    ['bananas', 5, 'apple', 4, 'apple', 3]],
columns=columns)
df
```

**Input**

```
    a              b                 c
  product   price   product price   product price
0   apple   1     oranges   2       bananas 1
1   oranges 4     bananas   3       oranges 2
2   bananas 5     apple     4       apple   3
```

**Code**

```
df = df.stack(0).reset_index(1).pivot(
    columns='level_1', index='product').reset_index()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0).rename(None)
df
```

**Output**

```
            a   b   c
0   apple   1   4   3
1   bananas 5   3   1
2   oranges 4   2   2
```